# Solver Foundation and the .NET GAC

Tags: c#, .net, gac, ms-solver-foundation

I have made an app using the microsoft solver foundation, and its great. But my problem is that my client haven't installed the microsoft solver foundation, so when the run the program they got this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Solver.Foundation,
>   Version=3.0.2.10889, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I think its because it is installed into the GAC, but I can do that on the clients machine, are there any work around?

Maybe I could use the dll only?

Comment: Have you tried to put the dll next to your exe?

Comment: Yes, and also tried to "Package the dll along with your application and refer it in your application." but it does not work

Comment: @MadsMonrad - So require your client install it.  You can even have your installer run the microsoft solver foundation before it installs your application.

Comment: I don't wish to install something on a clients PC. So that is not a option.

Comment: Try to check if the solver foundation has any dependencies that are installed into the GAC and put those dependencies next to your .exe

Comment: @MadsMonrad Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: Nope, my solution was not to use solver foundation :(